# Is there any free crypto wallet api available

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Can anyone tell that is there any free crypto wallet api available which one can use in a project

Comment: Please elaborate on what "free crypto wallet api" means, how you're project uses it, etc.

Comment: Like spectrocoin ,coinbase wallet api are there but to send coins from one account to another there is no balance in the test cases provided by them